# why doesn't this .htacess file prevent users from accessing content I want secured?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to accomplish several things with this .htacess file, but cannot seem to
get it to serve the rewrites I need, while preventing unathorized access to files I want
hidden.  My goal is to allow any file located in /sections/section_name/webroot/ to be accessed through /section_name/.  So, /admin/images/kittens/cat.jpg would serve up /sections/admin/webroot/images/kittens/cat.jpg if it existed.  I want to be able to have multiple sections.  If a section is not specified, but the file exists in /sections/default/webroot, then I'd like for that to be served. Any other request should
go to /dispatcher.php.  I thought I had this working, until I requested a configuration
file in /config and was able to see it.  Then I realized I could basically view any file
if I knew that path.

How can I fix this security issue while still keeping the rewrites working?

Here is my .htacess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

# If a file is requested in the admin webroot, and it exists, allow it to pass through
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^admin(/.*)$ sections/admin/webroot/$1 [L,QSA]

# if the requested url begins with /customers and it is located in /sections/customers/webroot
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^customers(/.*)$ sections/customers/webroot/$1 [L,QSA]

# if the requested url begins with /resellers and it is located in /sections/resellers/webroot
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^resellers(/.*)$ sections/resellers/webroot/$1 [L,QSA]

# if the requested file does not begin with /admin, /customers, or /resellers, and is in /sections/default/webroot, then serve it
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/sections/default/webroot/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sections/default/webroot/$1 [QSA,L,NC]

# Send everything else to the dispatcher
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't quite a solution, but have you tried cutting it all the way down and then adding the rules back one by one, testing each one along the way? For starters, if you can get files in /config that you're not supposed to, I'd try cutting everything except the final rule (which is supposed to send requests in /config to dispatcher) and see if that works. If it does, keep adding things back slowly until you see which specific rule is allowing /config files to be seen. Then you know what to fix.

Comment: I tried this and came to the conclusion that the issue was really the last rule.  Thank you.  At the end I ended up just saying that if the file wasn't in a webroot and wasn't the dispatcher, to pass back to the dispatcher (which would issue my own 404).

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to the end worked.  Anything that wasn't a valid file requested in one of the
webroot folders, and that wasn't a call to dispatcher.php, was redirected to dispatcher.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/dispatcher.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sections/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+/webroot/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatcher.php [QSA,L]
```